# Why isn't this mod-rewrite to a different directory working?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a link on the main page to

```
www.example.com/test
```

I have a page in a pages directory, called `test.php`

Here's what my .htaccess looks like:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond pages/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ pages/$1.php
```

Now, I can get it to work with `RewriteRule ^test$ pages/test.php`, but as soon as I put in the regex, it won't work.  Also, the RewriteCond rule doesn't seem to work either.  Any solutions you can think of?  I have tried adding `Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews` but it didn't work.

### update

If I add a test.php to the main directory, then change `RewriteCond pages/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]` to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]` then it works; so that is where the problem is.

I can't figure out how to check if the file exists in the `pages` directory.

Comment: What is happening? Are you seing an "Internal Server Error" or "Redirect Loop"?

Comment: Yeah, specific errors are nice.

Comment: Error 404. It can't find the page.

Comment: @bkconrad Didn't work.  It doesn't check in the pages directory for the file, which it needs to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REQUEST_FILENAME is the full ***server*** path. So if your document root path is `/home/website/public/` you are trying to check if `pages/home/website/public/test.php` exists, which of course it doesn't.

Here are the rules you want.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ pages/$1.php
```

Comment: Hmmm. Not working. Doesn't affect index.php, but example.com/test gives me a 404.

Comment: And you have a file called test.php in the pages directory? If you're on Linux, case matters. This is working for me in my tests.

Comment: Yes. test.php is in the pages directory.  I can get it to work no problem if they are in the same directory, but I can't figure out how to check if the file exists in another directory.

Comment: I just independently came up with this as well. If this doesn't work, you're omitting configuration details.

Comment: Change your RewriteRule line to `RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ pages/$1.php [R]` to see if your rule is being hit, and if it is, where your browser gets redirected to. Are you running your site on localhost in a directory, something like http://localhost/mysite/ ?

Comment: Be careful: `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` doesn't work if you are using a shared hosting provider.  Such mass customised solutions don't set a per-user `DocumentRoot`, so look at your `phpinfo()` for a variable like PHP_DOCUMENT_ROOT  in which case you will be able to use `%{ENV:PHP_DOCUMENT_ROOT}` instead or even just hardcode it -- e.g. `RewriteCond /home/userA/public_html/pages/$1.php -f` (or whatever yr DOCROOT is.

Comment: @TerryE Good info. The htaccess here is right, but the value of DOCUMENT_ROOT may not be.

Comment: @TerryE Your hardcoded RewriteCond works, but I can't seem to get the variable to work.  Is there no other variable that I could try?

Comment: Do a phpinfo() and and take a look at the `Apache Environment` section. All those variables should be available to you in .htaccess.